# Sharing Session in App and in webview inside the app - IOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

Hi I have IOS application written in swift that has login and after the successful login the app segues to activity that has `webView`.

the app and the website shares the same api. The process of the login is when I supply correct `username` and `password` the api return `token`

I managed the app login correctly using the Alamofire framework as http request

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: param).responseJSON{ (request, response, JSONdata, error) in
            if error != nil {
                let result = ["Error" : "Unexpected Error!"]
                callback(result: result)
            } else {
                if response?.statusCode == 401 {


                        println(401)
                        let result = ["Error" : "User not found!"]
                        callback(result: result)


                } else if response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    let responseDict = JSONdata as! NSDictionary
                    callback(result:responseDict)
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is my displaying of webview code

```
let requestURL = NSURL(string: "myURL")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

webView.loadRequest(request)
```

I need to display the website inside the webview it's happening but I need to share the session to webview since they share same api with the app.

could anyone help me? how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass token as a body to Request You can do as below.It is in Objective C,convert it into swift.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://your_url.com"];
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"token=%@",varToken];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[webView loadRequest: request];
```

Comment: I just want the user of the app already logged on in the webview, but I don't have idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to share the session between the app and the webview, the cookies needs to be shared between them, so before loading the webview set the cookies.

In this function pass your cookie and set your request value to `myRequest`

```
var myRequest : URLRequest?

func setCookie(cookie:HTTPCookie) {
    let setCookites = DispatchQueue(label: "perform_task_with_cookies")
    let loadWebview = DispatchQueue(label: "perform_task_with_loadwebview")
    setCookites.sync {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            webView.configuration.websiteDataStore.httpCookieStore.setCookie(cookie, completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookieAcceptPolicy = HTTPCookie.AcceptPolicy.always
            myRequest?.allHTTPHeaderFields = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies!)
            myRequest?.httpShouldHandleCookies = true
        }
    }
    loadWebview.sync {
        if let request = self.myRequest {
            self.webView.load(request)
        }
    }
}
```